# Iterated differential operator

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, symbolic, operators

I would like to implement the following differential operator in Mathematica,

$$
\prod_{j=1}^n \left({\mathrm d \over \mathrm d x}-j\right)
$$

On a case by case basis, I can just expand it out and write things in terms of `D[f, {x, j}]` for $ j = 1, 2, \dots, n $, but I would like to know how to define a function that works for general $ n $.

Comment: Is the product actually a product? You mention `D[f,{x,j}]` which takes the $j$th derivative of f w.r.t x, but (for univariate f) you could also mean `op[f_, x_, n_] := Product[D[f[x], x] - j, {j, 1, n}]`

Comment: Sorry for poor wording. The product is supposed to define an $n$-th order differential operator. So for example, when applied to a test function $f[x]$ the $n=2$ case would give $f''[x]-3 f'[x]+2f[x]$.

Comment: Please explain how you get that result - it's not obvious to me.

Comment: For $n=2$ the differential operator of interest is $(d/dx-1)(d/dx-2)= d^2/dx^2 - 3 d/dx + 2$. Then just apply this to the test function.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71643/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125277/1871  Also, you may want to try this package: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162590/1871

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Defining the operator recursively,

```
dOp[func_, x_Symbol, 1] := dOp[func, x, 1] = D[func, x] - func;

dOp[func_, x_Symbol, n_Integer?Positive] := dOp[func, x, n] =
   D[dOp[func, x, n - 1], x] - n*dOp[func, x, n - 1];
```

For example,

```
dOp[f[x], x, 2] // Expand

(* 2 f[x] - 3 f'[x] + f''[x] *)
```

Looking at the first several,

```
Table[{n, dOp[f[x], x, n] // Expand}, {n, 1, 6}] // 
 Grid[#, Alignment -> Left, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]

The coefficients are Stirling numbers of the first kind, [`StirlingS1`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StirlingS1.html)

```
Table[StirlingS1[n, m], {n, 2, 7}, {m, 1, n}] // Grid
```

[image]

Consequently, the operator can alternatively be written as the sum

```
dOp2[func_, x_Symbol, n_Integer?Positive] :=
 Sum[StirlingS1[n + 1, m + 1] D[func, {x, m}], {m, 0, n}]
```

Verifying the equivalence of the definitions,

```
And @@ Table[dOp[f[x], x, n] == dOp2[f[x], x, n] // Simplify, {n, 1, 15}]

(* True *)
```

Comment: +1 for `StirlingS1` :)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response!

Answer (score 8):

One can use `Composition` (which should be the true meaning of the product of operators) with (pure) `Function`:

```
ClearAll[op, ff]
ff[j_] := f \[Function] D[f, x] - j f
op[n_] := Composition @@ Table[ff[j], {j, n}]
```

```
op[2][f[x]] // Simplify
```

> 2 f[x] - 3 f'[x] + f''[x]

---

**Update**

The version without `Apply (@@)` (actually `Composition` can be also replaced by `RightComposition`, because the order seems not to matter much in this case), by virtue of a syntax of `Array` able to replace heads:

```
Clear[op2]
op2[n_] := Array[ff, n, 1, Composition]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

```
op[f_, x_, n_] := Block[{d}, 
  Total[MapIndexed[#1*If[#2[[1]] == 1, 1, D[f[x], {x, #2[[1]] - 1}]] &, 
    CoefficientList[Product[d - j, {j, 1, n}], d]]]]
```

`op[g, y, 2]` gives `2 - 3 g'[y] + g''[y]`

---

Update based on your comment:

```
op[f_, x_, n_] := 
 Block[{d}, 
  Total[MapIndexed[#1*D[f[x], {x, #2[[1]] - 1}] &, 
    CoefficientList[Product[d - j, {j, 1, n}], d]]]]
```

`op[g, y, 2]` gives `2*g[y] - 3*g'[y] + g''[y]`

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I actually want the lowest term to be 2f[x] instead of 2, but this is easily fixed by changing the 1 after #2[[1]] == 1 to f[x].