# How to calculate an iterated derivative in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-transforms

I try to calculate an inverse Mellin transform for $s^n \Gamma(s)$:
$$x\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(e^{-x}\right)\right)$$ for $n=2$
for $n$ as $$\left(x\text{}\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\right)^ne^{-x}$$
I try `NestList` and `Do` but it does not work; it is simple but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Have you seen `InverseMellinTransform[]` already?

Comment: Can you show what you tried with NestList and Do so we can see where the issue is?

Comment: Possible duplicate:  [(214105)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/214105). Also related: [(67184)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67184), [(71643)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71643), [(125277)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125277).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is:

```
f[n_] := If[n == 0, E^-x, (-1)^n*Nest[x D[#, x] &, x D[Exp[-x], x], n - 1] // Simplify]

(*for n >= 0 and n is integer *)

f[2]
(*E^-x (-1 + x) x*)

Grid[{Table[f[n], {n, 0, 5}], Table[InverseMellinTransform[s^n Gamma[s], s, x], {n, 0, 5}]}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: hi @Mariusz Iwaniuk I LIKE YOUR METHOD IT IS MORE SIMPLE IT IS P0SSIBLE TO GET THE FORMULA INCLUSIVE WHEN F(0) WHEN N=0 GIVE AND ERROR THAT THE VALUES OBVIOSLY IS THE FUNCTION ITSELF, AND IT IS POSSIBLE TO GET THE TERM WHE N=0 THANKS

Comment: @capea. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Mariusz Iwaniuk works fine

Answer (score 6):

You are basically differentiating with respect to `Log[x]`, which is possible using the [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction) ["ChainD"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ChainD):

```
ResourceFunction["ChainD"][Exp[-x],{Log[x],2}]
```

> -E^-x x + E^-x x^2

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

There are multiple ways of implementing the differential operator

```
dOp1[f_, n_Integer?NonNegative, sym : _Symbol : x] :=
 Nest[Simplify[sym*D[#, sym]] &, f, n]

dOp2[f_, n_Integer?NonNegative, sym : _Symbol : x] :=
 Sum[StirlingS2[n, k]*sym^k*D[f, {sym, k}], {k, 0, n}]

dOp3[f_, n_Integer?NonNegative, sym : _Symbol : x] :=
 D[f /. sym :> E^sym, {sym, n}] /. sym :> Log[sym]
```

Comparing the implementations

```
And@@Table[dOp1[f[x], n] == dOp2[f[x], n] == dOp3[f[x], n], {n, 0, 15}] // 
  Simplify

(* True *)
```

For the special case of `f[x] == E^-x`

```
And@@With[{f = E^-x}, 
 Table[dOp1[f, n] == dOp2[f, n] == dOp3[f, n] == 
    (-1)^n*InverseMellinTransform[s^n Gamma[s], s, x], {n, 0, 15}] // 
  Simplify]

(* True *)
```